# Nginx rewrite non-existent files under sub directory with rewrite rules

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

Nginx rewrite from .php to .php under same location

I am trying to move a site with a large number (93) of .htaccess files from Apache to Nginx.
There are over 800 rewrite rules to convert. To optimize performance, I have decided to
place the rules under separate nested location blocks (61 blocks in total).

But I am having problem with rewriting some of the rules.

## Requirements:

1. /test/abc/pics/ should redirect to /test/abc/wallpapers/
2. /test/abc/pics/800/a.jpg should be served directly, if the file is present. If it does not exist,
   then the request should be rewritten to /test/abc/pics/pic.php, which will
   create the file on first request. Subsequent requests will be served directly.
3. /test/abc should redirect to /test/abc.html
4. /test/abc.html should be rewritten to /test/index.php
5. /test/abc/def/year-2014.php should be rewritten to /test/abc/def/index.php
6. All static files (.gif, .jpg, .png, .mpg....) should be served directly with a very long expiry time.
7. All files ending in .html should be served directly. If the file does not exist the request should be rewritten to /fallback.php
8. All files ending in .php or / should be executed by PHP-FPM. If the file does not exist it should be rewritten to /fallback.php

## Config:

```
index index.php;

#
# Location Specific Rules
#
location /test/abc/ {
    location /test/abc/pics/ {
        # For ensuring 'serve directly, if file exists' condition of Rule 2
        try_files $uri @rewrite_pics; 
    }

    location /test/abc/def/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/index.php @rewrite_def;
    }
}

location /test/ {
    rewrite "^/test/([a-z-]+)$" /test/$1.html permanent; # Rule 3
    rewrite "^/test/([a-z-]+).html$" /test/index.php?symbol=$1 last; # Rule 4
}

location @rewrite_pics {
    rewrite "^/test/abc/pics/$" /test/abc/wallpapers/ permanent; # Rule 1
    rewrite "^/test/abc/pics/([0-9]+)/(.*)$" /test/abc/pics/pic.php?width=$1&height=$1&pic=$2 last; # Rule 2
}

location @rewrite_def {
    rewrite "(?i)^/test/abc/def/year-([a-z]+).php$" /test/abc/def/index.php?year=$1 last;
}

#
# Fallback Rules
#
location ~* \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|3gp|flv|mpg|mpeg|mp4|mp3|swf|txt|xml|pdf|zip)$ {
    expires 1M; # Rule 5
    try_files $uri /404.php;
}

location ~ (\.php|\.html|/)$ {
    try_files $uri "${uri}index.php" /fallback.php =404;
    include php-fpm.conf;
}
```

**php-fpm.conf**

```
include fastcgi.conf;
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
```

## Problem:

1. Since the fallback rules are regular expressions, they are selected instead of the location specific rules
2. If I use `~` prefix for all location specific rules, then the fallback rules are never executed.
   Request for `/test/abc/pics/800/a.jpg` will be rewritten to `/test/abc/pics/pic.php` which will again match the
   same location config. So the file is not executed and is downloaded as is.
3. So, I added '`include php-fpm.conf;`' to all location blocks (except named locations). But this causes all
   requests under `/test/abc/pics/` (including existing `.jpg` files) to pass to the PHP-FPM. Which leads to an access denied error,
   since only `.php` extension is allowed by `security.limit_extensions`.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a simple way to have all existing files served based on their extension
and only non existent files match the location blocks / rewrite rules?